# APNs not delivered to Ad-Hoc build

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am working with an App which is using Apple Push Notifications.

I have permissions to use Push Notifications granted to the app.

When I was using xCode to install App I was able to receive APNS. However, when prepared ad-hoc build of my application the server (which is using URL = gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com ) was receiving from the service error "Invalid token".

So we decided to provide Production Certificate to server and it caused that there is no error returned but also no notification was delivered.

I have checked also app package and it seems to be OK:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>application-identifier</key>
<string>XXXXXX</string>
<key>aps-environment</key>
<string>production</string>
<key>com.apple.developer.team-identifier</key>
<string>XXXXXX</string>
<key>get-task-allow</key>
<false/>
<key>keychain-access-groups</key>
<array>
<string>XXXXXX</string>
</array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I am looking for a solution.

- I have APN Production Cert in Keychain Access (but without Private Key), but I can obtain a p12 file and import it that way with private key
- Maybe URL is wrong (but why it gives no error?)

I will be grateful for any help related to solving my problem.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem now was that we have been using for our tester ad-hoc deployment with development provisioning profile. And with X-Code6 there is no longer possible to do such thing. As a workaround we use XCode6 to package everything and XCode5 to export it.